# negative semidefinite matrix

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

I got a positive definite matrix $B$, that is, $V(x)=x^TBx>0$ for any vector $x≠0$. I am clear with the statement that  $λ_\min∥x∥_2^2≤V(x)≤λ_\max∥x∥_2^2$ for any $x≠0$, where $λ_\min$ and $λ_\max$ are defined by
\begin{align}λ_\min&=\min\{|λ|:λ\text{ is an eigenvalue of }B\}\\
\text{and }\qquad
λ_\max&=\max\{|λ|:λ\text{ is an eigenvalue of }B\} 
\end{align}
Now my question is that whether this relation holds true if $B$ is a  negative definite matrix??

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

1. $B$ is negative definite $ \iff -B$ is positive definite.
2. $ \lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $B \iff - \lambda$ is an eigenvalue  of $-B.$

Can you proceed ?